# Using $scope in AngularJS to change value at index.html in routing

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm making a single page app in AngularJS using Firebase and using the side nav bar on index.html.

And after login, I want the username should be on the side nav bar but the $scope is working for the current page on the controller is working.

```
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.validateLogin = function() 
    {
        var email = $scope.login.userName + "@xyz.co";
        var password = $scope.login.password;
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.message = "please enter the correct details";
        });
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) 
        {
            if(user)
            {
                $scope.usermobile = $scope.login.userName;
                window.location.assign("/#/equipment");
            }
        });
    }
    $scope.message = '';
});
```

Comment: I don't understand this piece: "but the $scope is working for the current page on the controller is working." - could you clarify?

Comment: Why not use `window.location.hash = "/#/equipment"; `

Comment: @CliveSeebregts
actually $scope works for the current routing page 
but i wants to chage the value of index.html page using that routing controller

Comment: so you want to move to the route `/#/equipment` after login. right?

Comment: I want the the user name should but added to the index.html 
after login using this controller.
as the side nav  bar on index.html contains the user details.

Comment: use $rootscope. for example $rootscope.username='name'. and in html you can use the value like `{{username}}`

Answer (score 0):

The current user is available in `firebase.auth().currentUser` as described in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentUser) so in your `mainController` you don't need to listen for auth changes.

In your code you are attaching a new listener each time the user tries to login, but what you actually want is to respond to one successful login, so just add a `then` to your sign in call:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(function (user) {
    console.log('the logged in user: ', user);
    // Go to the other route here.
    // It is recommended to use the router instead of "manually" changing `window.location`
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    $scope.message = "please enter the correct details";
  });
```